# Can't fetch data with Ruby and Basecamp API

Tags: ruby, api, activeresource, basecamp

My code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'basecamp'
basecamp = Basecamp.establish_connection!('example.basecamphq.com', 'example', '123456', true)
projects = Basecamp::Project.find(:all)
projects.inspect
```

It gives:

```
/Users/kir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@project/gems/activeresource-3.1.0/lib/active_resource/base.rb:922:in `instantiate_collection': undefined method `collect!' for #<Hash:0x105faa450> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/kir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@project/gems/activeresource-3.1.0/lib/active_resource/base.rb:894:in `find_every'
    from /Users/kir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@project/gems/activeresource-3.1.0/lib/active_resource/base.rb:806:in `find'
    from bs.rb:4
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: It seems that `active_resource` is expecting an `Array` on row 922 (which does have a `collect!` function). However, it is receiving a `Hash`. Strange. You will have to debug `active_resource` and see the contents of that `Hash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some problems with the [basecamp wrapper gem](https://github.com/anibalcucco/basecamp-wrapper) and rails >= 3.1.x. The "undefined method `collect!'" error was one of them. I pushed some fixes and bumped the gem version to 0.0.7 which should solve that and other problems.